# Using jQuery, ajax and java to store an image

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update an image from a dynamically created tab. Initially the original image displays correctly; however, the resulting updated image will not display so the data I have saved is not correct.

HTML (dynamically created):

```
//Column 2 to contain the image
contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="'+obj.eventId+'">Photograph:</label>';
contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 photo-input" type="file" id="'+obj.eventId+'" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
contents += '<img id="campImage'+obj.eventId+'" src="' + obj.eventPicture + '" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
contents += '</div>';
```

jQuery/javascript/ajax:

```
        var img = document.getElementById('campImage'+ this.id);

        $.ajax({
            url: "CampUpdateView",
            data : {
                "campID" : this.id,
                "startDate" : $('#startDate'+ this.id).val(),
                "endDate" : $('#endDate'+ this.id).val(),
                "location" : $('#location'+ this.id).val(),
                "details" : $('#details'+ this.id).val(),
                "nights" : $('#nights'+ this.id).val(),
                "building" : $('#building'+ this.id).val(),
                "canvas" : $('#canvas'+ this.id).val(),
                "actualKM" : $('#actualKM'+ this.id).val(),
                "offset" : $('#offset'+ this.id).val(),
                "outcome" : $('#outcome'+ this.id).val(),
                "photo" : img.getAttribute('src'),
            },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
```

Photo data fragment: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBD"

This is passed to java on the client side which calls the server side to perform the update. In the update SQL I set the photo to this value in a prepared statement.

Client Side:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Get the variables from local storage
    String photo = request.getParameter("photo");

    System.out.println("photo: " + photo);

    //Update Camp
    MySQLConnection.updateEvent(campID, startDate, endDate, location, details, nights, building, canvas,
            outcome, photo, actualKM, offset);

}
```

Server Side:

```
public static void updateEvent(String eventID,
        String startDate, String endDate, String location, String details,
        String nightsInCamp, String inBuilding, String underCanvas,
        String kmTravelled, String picture, String kmTravelledActual, 
        String kmTravelledOffset) {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    // Create connection/statement variables outside of try block
    Connection c = null;

    String updateWithPhoto = ("UPDATE at_event " +
                              "SET event_date_start = ?, " +
                                "event_date_end = ?, " +
                                "event_location = ?, " +
                                "event_details = ?, " +
                                "event_nights = ?, " +
                                "event_nights_building = ?, " +
                                "event_nights_canvas = ?, " +
                                "event_picture = ?, " +
                                "event_km = ?, " +
                                "event_km_actual = ?, " +
                                "event_km_offset = ? " +
                              "WHERE event_id = ?;");

    try {
        // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
        c = ds.getConnection();

        try {

            // Create a statement and execute the query on it
            ps = c.prepareStatement(updateWithPhoto);
            ps.setString(1, startDate);
            ps.setString(2, endDate);
            ps.setString(3, location);
            ps.setString(4, details);
            ps.setString(5, nightsInCamp);
            ps.setString(6, inBuilding);
            ps.setString(7, underCanvas);

            ps.setString(8, picture);

            ps.setString(9, kmTravelled);
            ps.setString(10, kmTravelledActual);
            ps.setString(11, kmTravelledOffset);
            ps.setString(12, eventID);

            ps.executeUpdate();

            // Clean up
            ps.close();
            c.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQLException in updateEvent: " + se.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Errors occurred in updateEvent: " + e.toString());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("SQLException in updateEvent: " + e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        // Ensure connection is closed and returned to the pool, even if errors occur.
        // This is *very* important if using a connection pool, because after all the
        // connections are used, the application will hang on getConnection(), waiting
        // for a connection to become available.
        // Any errors from the following closes are just ignored.  The main thing is
        // that we have definitely closed the connection.
        try {
            if(ps != null) ps.close();
            if(c != null) c.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in updateEvent: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Done
}
```

Comment: so, `obj.eventPicture` is `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBD...."`  - so, you're saving that string in the database, right. Perhaps you're "doing something wrong"™ in server side code that you haven't shared

Comment: where is jquery callback?

Comment: I have added the client side and server side code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by jquery callback. The image is stored on bitton click "contents += '<button id="'+obj.eventId+'" class="btn btn-large btn-primary update-button" type="button">Update</button>';"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to strip of the starting description:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('campImage'+ this.id);
img2 = (img1.getAttribute('src')).replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif);base64,/, "");
```

Then on the server side:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(picture);
ps.setBlob(8, new SerialBlob(imageByte));
```

Where "picture" is the string (without "data:image/jpeg;base64,").